# Running custom mongodb queries in java

Tags: java, mongodb, database-connection, bson

I want to run raw mongoDb queries using runCommand() which takes in BSON data. 
Following is my code

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("MyDB");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = (MongoCollection<Document>)database.runCommand(??);
```

If my query is

> db.mycol.find({"by":"tutorials point"}).

What should be BSON data that I have to pass inside runCommand() ? Is it only

> {{"by":"tutorials point"}}

or

> db.mycol.find({"by":"tutorials point"}).

And If instead of find() i have to use Insert() how to go about it ??

Answer (score 1):

Find:

```
db.runCommand({
    find: "mycol",
    filter: { by: "tutorials point"}
})
```

Insert:

```
db.runCommand({
    insert: "mycol",
    documents: [ { _id: 1, foo: "bar"} ]
})
```

I think the easiest why to do it in java is to use Jongo (http://jongo.org/). 
Syntax is very similar to mongo shell.

```
jongo.runCommand("{find: 'mycol', filter: { by: 'tutorials point'}}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that.
First of all you need to get your `collection`

like : `MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("test");`

Once you have the `collection` you can run the raw query by using the util `import com.mongodb.util.JSON;`

this would be an example that you want to do:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("MyDB");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("mycol");

String rawQuery = "{\"by\": \"tutorials point\"}";

DBObject query = (DBObject) JSON.parse(rawQuery);
collection.find(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give example of how it work
this was my **query**

```
db.getCollection('Collection').aggregate([{
    $unwind: '$somearray'
}, {
    $match: {
        _id: ObjectId("123456"),
        'somearray.type': "blabla"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        '_id':0,
        'name': '$somearray.name',
        'phone': '$phone'
    }
}])
```

This was my Java program that did the same as query

```
public MongoIterable < Document > GetList(String collectionName, String id) {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("MyDB");
    MongoCollection < Document > collection = database.getCollection("collectionName");
    Document match = Document.parse("{_id: ObjectId('" + id + "'),'somearray.type': 'blabla'}");
    Document project = Document.parse("{ $project: { _id: 0,'name': '$somearray.name'},  'phone': '$phone'}");
    MongoIterable < Document > output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.unwind("$somearray"), Aggregates.match(match), project));
    return output;
}
```